# Configure ACTIVEMQ_OPTS in ActiveMQ 5.15.4

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I was trying to send an `ObjectMessage` containing a `myObject`, instance of `myClass`, using ActiveMQ as JMS Provider. Call to ActiveMQ is made through Mule 4.3.0.

An error occurred in the receiving application:

```
Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to  broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class client.MyClass! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
```

the page says:

> If you need to exchange object messages, you need to add packages your applications are using. You can do that with by using
> `org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES` system property of the
> broker. You can add this system property to `ACTIVEMQ_OPTS` variable in
> `${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/bin/env` script.

I am using ActiveMQ 5.15.4 . In the `\bin` subfolder, there is no `env` script, only the `activemq` script.

Where should I configure `ACTIVEMQ_OPTS` so that I, will not get forbidden class error. Or if any alternative solutions will help.

Comment: This question is unrelated to Mule, since Mule is only the client and the question is about server configuration.

Comment: I recommend you to migrate away from `javax.jms.ObjectMessage` completely. It is cumbersome and error prone since every client needs to have the object's class on its classpath. Furthermore, it is generally considered a security risk (thus the requirement to configure "trust" for deserialization) and it is _slow_. Finally, it precludes the use of any non-Java clients. If you ever need to expand your solution to clients not running Java you won't be able to.

Answer (score 0):

You should define ACTIVEMQ_OPTS in your operating system shell, using the appropriate method for that operating system. For example in Linux set it in the user's profile script, or use the bin/env script.

If you are using Windows you can set it [using the UI](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/windows-set-environment-variable).